# Get values from database in drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
<ui-select ng-model="apptDetails.profile" name="profile" theme="bootstrap" ng-required="true">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Profile" >{{$select.selected.Profile_name}}
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices
       repeat="profile.Profile_id as profile in profileList | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="profile.Profile_name | highlight: $select.search" ></span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I need to get values from database and its already displayed in dropdown, I get values in ng-model but it cant be set in drop down (not in option) however if I send post request it works.

e.g: if profile is abc on database for particular user, it displays on that dropdown pre selected. When I get information for that user in form, all the text fields get data from model but it cant be shown in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you make JS Fiddle for it

Comment: what do mean by JS Fiddle?

Comment: It is an online platform where you can run and test your js and html code online

Comment: i m doing in my own project.

Comment: please share your js code as well

Comment: vm.AppointmentData = AppointmentService.editDetails(vm.ApptId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.apptDetails = response.editDetails;$scope.profileList = response.profileList;            in apptDetails i get user selected profile from database and in profilelist iget array of profile for dropdown option.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Basically i just created a plunker for you but it also works as it should be... May be it  can help you... https://plnkr.co/edit/43ToW4?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have done something wrong... As i created a demo on `plunker`, its working fine.
May be it can help you...

https://plnkr.co/edit/43ToW4?p=preview

Comment: is ngSanitize need cuz i does't inject in controller or module??

Comment: Don't you have injected `ui.select` in your angular module definition.

Comment: yes i injected that one. when i debug i get profile_id and name from database in editDetails. but its not set just like you provide a link from plnkr

Comment: Can you send me any errors you are getting inside console. ?

Comment: yes its work now, i found my mistake. after looking response edit detail i found that i get data from object inside object and i have to change $select.selected.Profile_name that Profile_name need to match from database column so that it bind. finally its work.

Comment: Whoever did this. Please don't do negative votes for accepted answers...  This may create negative effect on our other stack overflow users having same kind of issue. Anyway whoever did this, may god bless him with his knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for ng-repeat

```
  <ui-select-choices
   repeat="profile in profileList | filter:$select.search">
    <span ng-bind-html="profile.Profile_name | highlight: $select.search" >     </span>
   </ui-select-choices>
```

Comment: no its also show id of that profile. however i used id to store on database.

Comment: you want to show all your details in span?

Comment: in ui select match tag

Comment: in order to get data in select you should bind your select with array  either with ng-repeat or ng-options

Comment: i get array in ui select choices. what i doing is when user click on edit button drop down value is pre selected if he wish to change it get a list on drop down else he left as it is with pre select that fetch from database.

Comment: you cant display all your details in your ui-select tag unless you bind some array with it

Comment: everything is work fine just what i need to do is when user click on edit on form it display all its details. this form include textbox radiobutton and drop down. when i click on edit button it should fetch all data from database in textbox except dropdown. i wishes to display pre selected choice that fetch from database. if user wants to change then it display array for choice.